# Which where the different file formats of GitHub recovery code files in the past?

Tags: github

I have to find my old recovery code file on a block device due to a corrupted (not damaged) block device.

Right now GitHub seems to use a text file, with one recovery code per line.

Was this different in the past (I think we file was created around 2014).

Unfortunately I do not remember.